# Consume a concat() XPath in Selenium and retrieve the text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am using one of the many XPath built-in functions (concat) to concatenate multiple elements on the page into a single string.

I want to consume this string in Selenium but I get an error when consuming the XPath. Here is the setup:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Thing One</th>
    <th>Thing Two</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr> 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**XPath**
`concat(//table//tr[1]/td[1], //table//tr[1]/td[2])`

**XPath Result**  (works)

"OneTwo"

**Consuming in Selenium:**

```
string xpath = "concat(//table//tr[1]/td[1], //table//tr[1]/td[2])"
OpenQA.Selenium.By MyBy = OpenQA.Selenium.By.XPath(xpath);
IWebElement element = Engine.WebDriver.FindElement(MyBy);
string text = element.Text;
```

An exception is thrown on the third line:

*"OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression concat(//table//tr[1]/td[1], //table//tr[1]/td[2]) because of the following error:
Error: value could not be converted to the specified type'"*

I would like to be able to consume the result of this XPath in Selenium.

***Update:**

**Use Case**
I'm building a utility which gets the values in the cells of a table (either across column or row). I need to run a contains() or startsWith() analysis on every cell. Instead of building a List and converting each element to Text, which takes a long time, I want to get a list of string for all the values and run through it programatically to find the indices for the matches. Knowing the indices of the matches I can then generate only the IWebElements that match.

Comment: In Selenium XPath couldn't return text or attribute, but WebElement only. You should perform concatenation using programming language built-in functions

Comment: Why would you `concatenate multiple elements`? Update the question with your _usecase_ / _steps_. Perhaps the HTML contains only one `<tr>` tag so you don't need an index `[1]` as in `tr[1]` even.

Comment: Added explanation

Comment: It looks like Selenium only allows path expressions that return nodes, not expressions that return strings.